# my implementation failed in removing the last character of String in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, error-handling

This is the LinkedList I defined:

```
typedef struct target{
  char my_target[65];
  int ID;
  struct target *next;
}target_list;
```

So Here's one solution which works:

```
printf("the last node is %s\n",get_nth(&head,target_id));
if (get_nth(&head,target_id)[strlen(get_nth(&head,target_id))-1] == '\n'){
  char *p = get_nth(&head,target_id);
  p[strlen(get_nth(&head,target_id))-1] = 0;
  //change_nth(&head,target_id);
  printf("the copied array is %s\n",p);

}
```

and it prints out as follows:

```
the last node is Git

the copied array is Git
```

But what I want to change the nth node in the linkedlist as follows: I define two helper methods, One for get the nth node, one for remove the '\n' in the char array of the nth node.

```
char* get_nth(target_list* head, int index)
{
  target_list* current = head;
  int cnt = 0;
  while(current != NULL){
    if (cnt == index)
      return(current -> my_target);
  cnt++;
  current = current -> next;
}
  return "";
}

void change_nth(target_list* head, int index)
{
  target_list* current = head;
  int cnt = 0;
  while(current != NULL){
    if (cnt == index){
      char *p = current -> my_target;
      p[strlen(current -> my_target)-1] = 0;
      strcpy(current -> my_target,"");
      strcpy(current -> my_target,p);

    }
  cnt++;
  current = current -> next;
}
}
```

And here's the changed main:

```
printf("the last node is %s\n",get_nth(&head,target_id));
    if (get_nth(&head,target_id)[strlen(get_nth(&head,target_id))-1] == '\n'){
      //char *p = get_nth(&head,target_id);
      //p[strlen(get_nth(&head,target_id))-1] = 0;
      change_nth(&head,target_id);
      printf("the copied array is %s\n",get_nth(&head,target_id));

    }
```

Here comes the error:

```
the last node is Git

==25553== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0x5201470, 0x5201470)
==25553==    at 0x4C2E272: strcpy (in *)
==25553==    by 0x40120F: change_nth (original.c:213)
==25553==    by 0x4015D6: main (original.c:318)
==25553== 
the copied array is
```

C string's be confusing me for long, Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some functions

```
char *removelast(char *str)
{
    size_t len;
    if(str == NULL) return NULL;
    if(!(len = strlen(str))) return str;
    str[len - 1] = 0;
    return str;
}

char *removenth(char *str, size_t nth) // nth - 0 to strlen - 1
{
    size_t len;
    if(str == NULL) return NULL;
    if(!(len = strlen(str)) || nth >= len) return str;
    strcpy(&str[nth], &str[nth + 1]);
    return str;
}


int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Hello stackoverflow!!";
    printf("Original      - %s\n", str);
    printf("Last removed  - %s\n", removelast(str));
    printf("Third removed - %s\n", removenth(str,2)); // third means 2
    return 0;
}
```

you can play with it yorself here https://ideone.com/Vnkzjp

You need to learn a bit about pointers and pointer manipulation